# Dynamic change dropdownlist and textbox by custom control

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, custom-controls, html-select

I want to write a custom control involving a `DropDownList` and a `TextBox`.
Actually,  I want to dynamically render `DropDownList` and  `TextBox`.
For example: when a user clicks a `Checkbox`, the `Textbox` will change to a `DropdownList`. On the other hand, when a user deselects the `Checkbox`, the `Dropdownlist` will change to a `Textbox`.

I know this can be done using two controls, which sets the visibility for both control. But can I do it on a custom control?

Comment: Do you want to do that on client- or on serverside?

Comment: Hi, i want do that on server side

Comment: Yes, you can create a new DropDownList/TextBox every time the user checks/unchecks a CheckBox. But the better(easier) approach is switching the visibility. There's at least no advantage from the other, why do you want to create them dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to go with that approach, here is your code.

In Design File:-

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
 oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />

 <div id ="control" runat="server">

 </div>
```

In Code Behind File:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
     TextBox txt = new TextBox();
     txt.ID = "txt";
     control.Controls.Add(txt);
   }
}
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (CheckBox1.Checked)
    {
       for (int ix = this.Controls.Count - 1; ix >= 0; ix--)
           if (this.Controls[ix] is TextBox) this.Controls[ix].Dispose();

       DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
       ddl.ID = "ddl";

      control.Controls.Add(ddl);
    }
    else
    {
      for (int ix = this.Controls.Count - 1; ix >= 0; ix--)
          if (this.Controls[ix] is DropDownList) this.Controls[ix].Dispose();

       TextBox txt = new TextBox();
       txt.ID = "txt";

       control.Controls.Add(txt);
    }
}
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: The dispose is totally unnecessary, all is diposed at the end of the page life-cycle automatically. Actually you won't find the proviously added control anymore at the next postback.

Comment: You haven't Looked at this Stack thread....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014286/removing-dynamically-created-controls-c-sharp

Comment: ...and you have overlooked the ASP.NET tag. What Hans suggests on your link is for Winforms only.

Comment: But note that even if you would remove the dispose part, your approach wouldn't work as expected. Especially Events and ViewState wouldn't work since the control must be recreated in `page_load` at the latest(`CheckedChanged` is too late to recreate the old, but ok for the new).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code

**ASPX**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="dynamicControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="dynamicControl" %>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
    oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" visible="false">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList1.Visible = CheckBox1.Checked;
    TextBox1.Visible = !CheckBox1.Checked;
}
```

This snippet will **show a dropDownList if** CheckBox is **checked** and *change* to **TextBox** if it's **not checked**. Despite this is possible *I don't think this is the right approach.* (eg: AutoPostBack needed, set visibility...)

What do you try to achieve?