# How to safely remove controls from TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a `tablelayoutpanel` with 128 cells that can be populated randomly with a panel that contains a `picturebox` and a `textbox`. What is the best practice to remove all panels with `picturebox` and `textbox` before repopulating the `tablelayoutpanel`? If not done properly, will there be memory leaks?

Comment: Yes.  You *have* to call the panel's Dispose() method.  Which will also remove it from the TLP.  Any child controls inside the panel are automatically disposed.

Comment: You may need to manually remove the image from the PictureBox first during an override of the Dispose(). It can continue to hold onto the reference to the image file. I ran into an issue with something like this on a project a year or two ago, and had to do that because it was causing issues with trying to delete the source file. It's just something to consider depending on what you're doing.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2014427/1080742