# Why does a Panel automatically scroll up when a different TextBox.Text is updated?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I've created a form and displayed it inside the panel but sadly the form can't fit. So I need to use `Panel.Autoscroll = True` in order to navigate the whole form.

When I click the `textbox1.text` in the lowest part of the form, the panel automatically scrolls up and the textbox can't be seen. Even if I scroll down it continuously scrolls up automatically.
How can I stop it from scrolling up?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
    Form2.TopLevel = False 
    Me.Panel1.Controls.Clear() 
    Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Form2) 
    Form2.Show() 
End Sub 

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick 
    Label2.Text = Date.Now.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy ddddddddd") 
    Label1.Text = Date.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")
End Sub
```

I realized the panel scrolls up when the date text is set to the label. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Is this winforms or asp.net?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this behavior but could not. Can you clarify "displayed a form inside a panel"? Is that a `Form` you put inside a `Panel` in another `Form`?

Comment: first i've created a form with a 2 panels.
first panel with dock in the second in order to have scroll bars. 

second created new form to be display that is longer than the panel  with a textbox below.
the form is borderless.

lastly
i display the second form with this code.

form2.TopLevel = False
Me.Panel1.Controls.Clear()
Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(form2)
form2.Show()

Comment: Can you show some code? How do you put the form inside the panel?

Comment: > form2.TopLevel = False 
> Me.Panel1.Controls.Clear() 
> Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(form2) 
> form2.Show()

Comment: I can only make it scroll to the top by resizing Form1. Do you have a loop that does that?

Comment: i dont have loop. it just automatically scrolls up when i click the textbox i dont know what does that.

Comment: do you think its a bug?

Comment: rethink your UI design

Comment: Please post your code in your question. Don't hide it within the comments.

Comment: Since I can't reproduce it with a minimal amount of code, there is something else going on. I don't think it's a bug.

Comment: ok i see whats the cause. its the timer. i have a clock display below in the status strip. And whenever it updates time, it makes the panel scrolls up which means every second.

Comment: ive tried to recreate it in a new project. heres my code.



Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Form2.TopLevel = False
Me.Panel1.Controls.Clear()
Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Form2)
Form2.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
Label2.Text = Date.Now.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy ddddddddd")
Label1.Text = Date.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")

Comment: @EzraBugarin Edit your original question and add the code.

Comment: Be careful, `Me.Panel1.Controls.Clear()` does not dispose of any objects in that collection.  It just moves them to an invisible container until you need them again.

Comment: @LarsTech interesting, so some reference is preserved making them ineligible for gc?

Comment: @Verdolino Correct (until the form is closed and disposed).  Better to dispose of the objects explicitly if that becomes an issue.

Comment: I think I will use Hans' extension method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969705/clear-controls-does-not-dispose-them-what-is-the-risk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve your problem by using your own panel and overriding the ScrollToControl function:

```
Public Class PanelEx
  Inherits Panel

  Protected Overrides Function ScrollToControl(c As Control) As Point
    Return Me.DisplayRectangle.Location
  End Function    
End Class
```

Replace your Panel1 panel with this new one in your ToolBox after rebuilding your solution.